# How to flash roms for samsung galaxy grand 2 single sim?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I have a samsung grand 2 single sim (G710) and I want to flash the G710S model or G7105 rom for it ... Is it Even possible and if yes...How?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't flash your phone with a different ROM.

In some rare cases that both hardware and software specs of the phones are similar it's possible but not in your case.(The phone will break if you do)

But if you want to flash your device with a new ROM or an updated version, here is the steps:

1. download the Firmware of your model number from [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/).
2. download [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) of your model and install it on computer. this will install the relevant drivers to identify the phone.
3. Unpack downloaded firmware and use [Odin](http://odindownload.com/) softwware and its PDA button to attach the downloaded firmware (The one with .md5 extension)
4. Put your phone in downloading mode by pressing VolDown+Home+Power while it's off. and connect it to computer.
5. After seeing "Added" message on Odin, use "Start" button to flash your samsung device.

hope it helps.